# Simplest way to use variable inside and outside a `syncExec` block (or, how to store a final reference to an object without initializing)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I successfully use `AtomicReference` in this example (the first thing I found that worked and was readable), but since I'm also using `syncExec` and the part outside the sync block will not be reached until the block has finished executing, I don't really need the reference to be atomic. It seems overkill.

```
final AtomicReference<Custom> result = new AtomicReference<>();

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec( () -> {
    Custom custom = getSomeCustom();
    custom.doSomething();
    result.set(custom);
});

Custom c = result.get();
c.doSomethingElse();
```

I tried to play around with regular references but I can't get it to work:

```
final Custom c;

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec( () -> {
    c= getSomeCustom();
    c.doSomething();
});

c.doSomethingElse(true);
```

It outputs `The final local variable view cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`, on the `getSomeCustom()` call.

I've also tried using `Reference` and its implementations, but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for (which is the most readable and basic way to do this). Does anybody have any idea how to achieve this without using `AtomicReference`?

Comment: There is now way around it: you need a mutable object. It could be an AtomicReference, or an actual Runnable class with a Custom field, or an array, for example. I'd go with a real class. The API should accept a Callable instead of a Runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to manage this is to have a final variable that you can put something into. For instance:

```
final Custom[] customHolder = new Custom[1];

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(() -> {
    customHolder[0] = getSomeCustom();
    customHolder[0].doSomething();
});

customHolder[0].doSomethingElse(true);
```

That will work as long as the lambda function is guaranteed to be called before the next line (i.e. if `syncExec` blocks the thread, which I believe it does).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to define a custom static method which accepts a `Supplier`:

```
public class UIUtils {
    static <T> T syncExec(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        Object[] obj = new Object[1];
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec( () -> {
            obj[0] = supplier.get();
        });
        return (T)obj[0];
    }
}
```

It's a little bit dirty as uses one-element array, but you'll need to write this method only once. After that you can use:

```
Custom c = UIUtils.syncExec(() -> {
    Custom custom = getSomeCustom();
    custom.doSomething();
    return custom;
});

c.doSomethingElse();
```